# Pointers to a nice test suite of programs for a cross compilation tool chain?

Tags: llvm, cross-compiling, llvm-clang, ellcc

I would like to find a nice test suite for my [ELLCC](http://ellcc.org) cross compiler project based on clang/LLVM. What I need are a bunch of programs to compile. For example, today I cross compiled tcsh for my supported targets: arm, armeb, i386, microblaze, mips, mipsel, ppc, and x86_64. All the Linux binaries ran.

I worked with the NetBSD pkgsrc stuff a bit to see if I could use it in a cross compilation environment and it is close to what I want but it will take a bit of work to be able to use it seamlessly. My host system is Linux and all the targets are currently Linux as well.

Any suggestions other than downloading each package separately, configuring, and building?

Comment: I'm not asking for a tool, I'm asking for a recommendation for a set of test programs similar to the NetBSD pkgsrc stuff but easier to cross compile. It is a specific need that my project has. It seems to me to be a reasonable question.

Comment: Actually, never mind. I've read the question more closely, and it was my misunderstanding of your question. Withdrawing the previous comments (and the close vote). My apologies. (In my own defense, the phrasing is misleading, as you ask for "Pointers to" the test suite, and say "I would like to find" in the opening sentence. It could perhaps be worded differently to avoid that appearance.) :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have the start of a solution: I'm starting to build the core NetBSD userland commands to run on Linux using ELLCC. I wrote up a short [description here](http://ellcc.org/blog/?p=1022).